# Run app.mydomain.com as mydomain.com/app on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I have a PHP app running on Heroku (app.herokuapp.com) and it is currently being pointed to app.mydomain.com. My question would be:

Is it possible to run app.mydomain.com at mydomain.com/app? Basically I would like the app to run in a subfolder as opposed to a subdomain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in a clean way (you could with iframes, but shouldn't go that way) point your application to a subdirectory in an other application.

That is because when not using the `x.herokuapp.com` domain name, you need to use [custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains). These relies on DNS entries to point to an application or an other.
And you cannot create DNS entries for a subdirectory.

What you could do though, is package one application at `example.com`, inside which you display whatever you want for the `/` url, and you load your application at the `/app` url.

Comment: Thank you. Sad to know that it's not possible. I forgot to mention that mydomain.com is hosted on GitHub Pages. Which makes it even more impossible to redirect app.mydomain.com as this will show the GitHub 404 page when it is redirected to mydomain.com/app.